# Programaticlly create Complication object to show on custom WearOS watchface

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I've got a simple watch face that I created in via Android Studio from the Watch Face template project and am trying to add a step counter complication to it.  The initialization is being done in this method that exists in the Engine class like so:

```kotlin
    private fun initializeComplications() {
        setDefaultSystemComplicationProvider(LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID, SystemProviders.STEP_COUNT, ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT)
        var complicationIds = listOf(LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID)
        setActiveComplications(LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID)
        leftComplicationDrawable = ComplicationDrawable(this@MyWatchFace)
        leftComplicationDrawable.setContext(applicationContext)
        leftComplicationDrawable.setBackgroundColorActive(Color.BLUE)
        leftComplicationDrawable.setTextColorActive(Color.WHITE)
        leftComplicationDrawable.setBackgroundColorAmbient(Color.BLUE)
        leftComplicationDrawable.setTextColorAmbient(Color.WHITE)
    }
```

and then adding it like so:

```kotlin
 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, bounds: Rect) {
     val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
     mCalendar.timeInMillis = now

     drawBackground(canvas)
     drawWatchFace(canvas)

     leftComplicationDrawable.setBounds(Rect(50, 50, 150, 150))
     leftComplicationDrawable.draw(canvas,now)
}
```

I cannot figure out why I'm not seeing the complication appear. Best I can tell from reading through the documentation and such I have all the necessary information in place to create the complication and since this is system information I don't have to worry about exposing additional data or some other service, I should just be able to hook directly into step counter.

Comment: anything in logcat?

Comment: @String Nothing in Logcat no.  I didn't see any errors, just the usual logs for the watch face.  I tried hooking up a debugger as well but wasn't able to get the connection done (this seems to be a reoccurring theme, not being able to debug a watch face because it doesn't have a default activity)